# Dynamically creating divs with position absolute which can expand to whole screen when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create something like this :
https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/

But the problem I face is that my divs are dynamic - could be any number that comes from a xhr service call. I'm trying to stack up divs but on click, they don't grow from their position to occupy the whole screen but grow from top left like this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJPNOq.

How can I achieve the same effect as in the first link for a dynamic list whose count can be unknown?

```
<div>
  <h1>Your dashboard</h1>
  <span class="close">X</span>
  <section class="parent">
    <section>room1</section>
    <section>room2</section>
    <section>room3</section>
    <section>room4</section>
    <section>room5</section>
    <sectoin>room6</sectoin>
  </section>
</div>

section section{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:green;
  margin:10px;
  padding:30px;
  transition:all .5s linear;
}

.parent{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.expanded{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:999;
  background-color:red;
}

.close{
  position:absolute;
  top:100;
  right:0;
  z-index:1000;
  cursor:pointer;
}

$('.parent section').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('expanded');
})

$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.parent section').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
  })
})
```

Comment: adding `width: 50%` and `float:left` to `section section {}` might work

Comment: You don't need jQ or JS for this effect. It can simply be done purely by CSS.

Comment: Can you show how can it be done for dynamic divs?

Comment: Did you try to change from position: absolute to position: fixed for class expanded.

Comment: yes. and it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo that shows how you can do this dynamically, it has a few issues if you spam click it but if you disable the click handler until it finishes the animation, they won't matter.  Alternatively you could cache the bounding values (you might want to anyway simply to avoid some of the reflows), but the specifics can change a lot depending on the website you're using this effect on.

Also I didn't implement the shrinking effect but I think it's probably fairly obvious how to do it based on the grow effect.

```js
const numberOfTiles = 9;
const totalColumns = 3;
const totalRows = Math.ceil(numberOfTiles / totalColumns);

const container = document.createElement('div');
Object.assign(container.style, {
  width: '80vw',
  height: '80vh',
  background: 'rgb(60, 61, 60)',
  transform: 'translate(10vw, 10vh)',
  lineHeight: 1 / totalRows * 100 + '%'
});

const tiles = [];
for (let row = 0; row < totalRows; ++row) {
  for (let col = 0; col < totalColumns; ++col) {
    if (tiles.length < numberOfTiles) {
      const tileContainer = document.createElement('div');
      Object.assign(tileContainer.style, {
        position: 'relative',
        width: 1 / totalColumns * 100 + '%',
        height: 1 / totalRows * 100 + '%',
        display: 'inline-block'
      });
      let randomColor = Math.ceil((Math.random() * Math.pow(255, 3))).toString(16);
      while (randomColor.length < 6) {
        randomColor = '0' + randomColor;
      }
      randomColor = '#' + randomColor;
      const tile = document.createElement('div');
      tile.classList.add('tile');
      Object.assign(tile.style, {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        background: randomColor,
        willChange: 'transform, left, top'
      });
      tile.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        if (tile.classList.toggle('fullscreen')) {
          let clientRect = tile.getClientRects();
          Object.assign(tile.style, {
            position: 'absolute',
            width: clientRect.width + 'px',
            height: clientRect.height + 'px',
            left: clientRect.left + 'px',
            top: clientRect.top + 'px',
            transition: '1s width, 1s height, 1s transform, 1s left, 1s top',
            zIndex: 100
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            let clientRect = tile.getBoundingClientRect();
            Object.assign(tile.style, {
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              width: '100vw',
              height: '100vh',
              transform: `translate(${-clientRect.left}px, ${-clientRect.top}px)`
            });
          }, 0);
        } else {
          Object.assign(tile.style, {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            transform: '',
            zIndex: 1
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            Object.assign(tile.style, {
              zIndex: 0
            });
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
      tiles.push(tile);
      tileContainer.appendChild(tile);
      container.appendChild(tileContainer);
    }
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(container);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: When you click on it multiple times, its position when it fills the screen is different. And the z-index of the other tiles sometimes is more than the expanded ones. And i really want to thank you for the wonderful script that you have written to make this work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I believe both of those issues go away if you disable the click handler on all the boxes until the transition is fully completed.  But the ideal way to do that depends a good bit on how your code is structured so I left it out of the example.  Or are you experiencing those issues even if you wait ~1-2 seconds between clicks?